# rest api post call from mobile device web page failed

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, rest, mobile

Below js code, it can be executed from desktop correctly, but "NetworkError" from mobile phone chrome:

```
$.ajax({
            url: apiurl + '/sys/login',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: (res) => {
                if (typeof res.userName === 'string') {
                    if (res.userName.trim().length > 0) {
                        cs.writeCookie("loginstatus", `T|${res.userName}|${res.userId}|${res.employeeName}|${res.employeeId}`, 2);
                        window.location.href = "/pages/kpis/msignin.html";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    console.log('login fail')
                }
            },
            error: (res) => {
                alert(JSON.stringify(res))
            }
        })
```

From mobile chrome it reports:

```
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://127.0.0.1/sys/login'"
```

Thanks!

I'm tried a lot like below and etc. but cannot solve it:

```
async: false,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is the loopback IP address. It is the IP address the browser is running on.

Your server is running on your desktop.

When your desktop browser asks for `127.0.0.1` then browser asks the server running on the desktop for the resource.

When your mobile browser asks for `127.0.0.1` then browser asks the server running on the mobile for the resource… but that server doesn’t exist.

Use an IP address for the server that the browser on the mobile can access.